# How does Datadog measure DAUs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, newrelic, datadog

Where does the **userstats.o1.daus** metric take the data from?

I looked in the metrics list and in the app, but I don't seem to find the source of the metric.

The application infrastructure relies on:

- AWS
- DynamoDB
- New Relic
- Amplitude

Comment: That's a custom metric most likely that you are submitting. If it came from one of the above, it would fall under that namespace most likely. While it could be related, I would check your metric summary page for that metric and look at the metadata/tags being applied for more insight on where it may be coming from.

Comment: @tqr_aupa_atleti Thanks. Yes, I just arrived there. I am a little new with this so I couldn't tell the difference. I looked at a tag "instance-type:m3.xlarge" and "region:us-east-1" so it looks like it is coming from AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to [@tqr_aupa_atleti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6815223/tqr-aupa-atleti) and the support team from Datadog.

On the Datadog dashboard panel, I had to click Metrics -> Summary and look for my metric. I looked at the tags and I could figure out it was a custom metric form my company that uses data from Amplitude.